# Next.js: How can I match my Layout to requested hostname?

Tags: next.js

I would like to give my website a custom layout depending on the hostname. Can I somehow access the hostname at the _app.js level?

Or is there another good way to implement this?

Comment: You can import the ```UseRouter``` from the ```next/router``` package which contains information about the current URL, including the hostname.

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida But the router does not give me any information about the domain name. Is there any way to get that and the subdomain?